# Android Studio - Cambio de fuente del texto al cambiar inputType programáticamente

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext, input-type

**Descripción:**

Estoy haciendo un diseño de *registro* típico, el cual permite mostrar u ocultar la contraseña.

**Problema:**

Cuando cambio el inputType de mis  editTexts, también se cambian las fuentes de los textos.

**Adjunto foto de mi diseño:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se aprecia claramente como el primer edit Text (E-mail) conserva la fuente que yo mismo le establecí (ya que no se cambia su inputType programáticamente). Ya en el segundo edit Text (Contraseña) se aprecia como cambió la fuente debido a que se seleccionó el botón que activa el "mostrado" de texto. Finalmente, el tercer edit Text (Repite tu contraseña) también cambia la fuente del texto porque se cambió su inputType a "password".

**Adjunto el código XML de mis Edit-Texts**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:background="@drawable/if_background_et_log_reg"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:hint="@string/e_mail"
    android:textColor="#4D4C4C"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="@font/source_sans_pro_regular"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_lore" />
```

**Adjunto el código JAVA del segundo Edit Text**

```
et_contraseña.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

**Adjunto el código JAVA del tercer Edit Text**

```
et_contraseña.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Me gustaría que por favor, alguien me indique que debo modificar para que el código JAVA el cual utilizo para cambiar los **Input Types** no cambie la fuente del texto original.

Muchas gracias por leer!

Answer (score 1):

Un opción para solucionar este problema es volver a definir el tipo de fuente a tu `EditText` después de definir el InputType, en este caso realizar lo siguiente:

```
et_contraseña.setInputType(.......);

Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(), R.font.source_sans_pro_regular);
et_contraseña.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: Gracias Jorge nuevamente. Tu código me funcionó pero ahora el texto queda sin el bold. También se lo puse programáticamente y ahora queda más bold de lo normal :(

Comment: @TomasM ok además de bold define 16sp de tamaño, eso es lo que se puede realizar en este caso.

Comment: También lo hice pero no funciona. Es muy raro esto del cambio de input type. :(